# My client wants their users to be able to add text, select from dropdowns, etc. on a 75 page doc. What libraries would you recommend for this task?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, forms, user-input

I am using React, RSuite, AWS, and Node for this project. I am at a complete loss as to  the best way to go about accomplishing this task. I have already tried putting all of the many, MANY paragraphs into JSON and then making it so that input fields pop up at certain points in the document, but it's just still turning out to be difficult to implement. I would really appreciate any guidance on how to get started on this task. (NOTE: I am NOT looking for code, I just was hoping for some brainstorming ideas that would give me a jumpstart on getting this project going.

Answer (score 3):

This is an open-ended question that will probably get closed. I'll be brief on the response with two suggestions.

First, I'd suggest a Content Management System (CMS) such as [Ghost](https://ghost.org) which their headless API can run behind your react app or you can customer a ghost theme. A common comparison is [WordPress vs Ghost](https://ghost.org/vs/wordpress/) which [WordPress](https://wordpress.com) is an older, but popular CMS. You can [get started here](https://ghost.org/docs/).

Second, if it's only this one doc, ever. You can look at [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api) for your react app to coordinate with their [documents data model](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents).

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are tasked to write an app that facilitates the building of a document paragraph-by-paragraph. For this, you can either implement someone else's CMS (content management system), or write your own somewhat simpler one.

If you write your own, you can store the paras (that make up the final document) in a MySQL table, and manage the order of the paragraphs (ie which comes first, which next, etc) via a numerical sort_order column, and allow the users to reposition each para up/down.

For user data entry, you can use a rich text editor such as Quill or TinyMCE or etc. These allow the user to input text (which gets inputted as HTML) with formatting ,such as bold, underline, font, color, etc. The result is HTML code that can be stored in your database.

Of course, you will also need a print button that will allow you to grab all the paras from the database table and print them onto a new page, as the formatted final document. Also, you can output them as a PDF - there are many libraries available that will facilitate that for you.

References:

https://areknawo.com/top-js-rich-text-editor-frameworks-for-2021/

https://stackhowto.com/how-to-print-a-pdf-file-using-javascript/

[YouTube video showing how to implement Quill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgreDlNaUn4)